# Rails 3 integration test fails with 406 response for simple html request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, integration-testing, http-status-code-406

I have an integration test the sends a simple GET request to the 'show' action.  I get a when I assert_response :success, it fails because the response is a 406, which means the format is **Not Acceptable HTTP**.

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserFlowsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  fixtures :continents, :countries, :types

  test "browse register order" do
    docs = make_docs
    assert_equal Doc.count, docs.length, "Docs not created properly"
    bob=new_session_as(:bob)
    bob.goes_to_home
    bob.goes_to_doc(1)
  end

  private

  module TestDSL
    def goes_to_home
      get root_url
      test_results("docs/index")
    end

    def goes_to_doc(id)
      get docs_url(id), #{:format => :html} - fails with this as well...
      y request.inspect
      p response.inspect
      test_results("docs/show")
    end

    def test_results(path)
      assert_response :success, "Checking #{path}"
      assert_template path
    end
  end #module TestDSL



  def new_session_as(person)
    new_session do |sess|
      #sess.goes_to_login
      #sess.logs_in_as(person)
      yield sess if block_given?
    end
  end

  def new_session
    open_session do |sess|
      sess.extend(TestDSL)
      yield sess if block_given?
    end
  end

end
```

Here is the request.inspect output:

> --- "#[],
>   \"action_dispatch.request.parameters\"=>{\"format\"=>\"1\",
>   \"action\"=>\"index\", \"controller\"=>\"docs\"},
>   \"rack.session\"=>{\"origin_url\"=>\"/docs.1?format=html\",
>   \"session_id\"=>\"6e0e0be703a2c2accf15121b1eb56668\"},
>   \"rack.test\"=>true,
>   \"HTTP_ACCEPT\"=>\"text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5\",
>   \"HTTP_HOST\"=>\"www.example.com\",
>   \"SERVER_NAME\"=>\"www.example.com\",
>   \"rack.request.cookie_hash\"=>{\"_id_session\"=>\"BAh7ByIPb3JpZ2luX3VybCIGLyIPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlNmUwZTBiZTcwM2EyYzJhY2NmMTUxMjFiMWViNTY2Njg=--ceb0f44d2ac8df81c888e005abb7e9d1df02e802\"},
>   \"action_dispatch.remote_ip\"=>#, \"CONTENT_LENGTH\"=>\"0\",
>   \"rack.url_scheme\"=>\"http\",
>   \"action_dispatch.request.query_parameters\"=>{\"format\"=>\"html\"},
>   \"action_dispatch.request.unsigned_session_cookie\"=>{\"origin_url\"=>\"/\",
>   \"session_id\"=>\"6e0e0be703a2c2accf15121b1eb56668\"},
>   \"CONTENT_TYPE\"=>\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\",
>   \"HTTPS\"=>\"off\", \"rack.errors\"=>#,
>   \"action_dispatch.secret_token\"=>\"8922d5d0a3e706818581l8cc2d42d9ce584ba6350de71e6afc49b2ad7d3d05c6e763db2615fca9eb123c51b57223d955a5199b60c20e5efb4be14888a4e3520a2\",
>   \"REMOTE_ADDR\"=>\"127.0.0.1\", \"PATH_INFO\"=>\"/docs.1\",
>   \"rack.version\"=>[1, 1], \"rack.run_once\"=>false,
>   \"action_dispatch.request.path_parameters\"=>{:format=>\"1\",
>   :controller=>\"docs\", :action=>\"index\"},
>   \"rack.request.cookie_string\"=>\"_id_session=BAh7ByIPb3JpZ2luX3VybCIGLyIPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlNmUwZTBiZTcwM2EyYzJhY2NmMTUxMjFiMWViNTY2Njg%3D--ceb0f44d2ac8df81c888e005abb7e9d1df02e802\",
>   \"SCRIPT_NAME\"=>\"\",
>   \"action_dispatch.parameter_filter\"=>[:password, :data],
>   \"action_dispatch.show_exceptions\"=>false,
>   \"HTTP_COOKIE\"=>\"_id_session=BAh7ByIPb3JpZ2luX3VybCIGLyIPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlNmUwZTBiZTcwM2EyYzJhY2NmMTUxMjFiMWViNTY2Njg%3D--ceb0f44d2ac8df81c888e005abb7e9d1df02e802\",
>   \"rack.multithread\"=>true,
>   \"action_dispatch.request.request_parameters\"=>{},
>   \"rack.request.form_vars\"=>\"\",
>   \"action_dispatch.cookies\"=>{\"_id_session\"=>\"BAh7ByIPb3JpZ2luX3VybCIYL2RvY3MuMT9mb3JtYXQ9aHRtbCIPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlNmUwZTBiZTcwM2EyYzJhY2NmMTUxMjFiMWViNTY2Njg=--529dbf0f8e243c4830526f37adb777bd9fba49fd\"},
>   \"REQUEST_URI\"=>\"/docs.1\", \"rack.multiprocess\"=>true,
>   \"rack.request.query_hash\"=>{\"format\"=>\"html\"},
>   \"rack.request.form_input\"=>#,
>   \"SERVER_PORT\"=>\"80\",
>   \"action_controller.instance\"=>#\"1\", \"action\"=>\"index\",
>   \"controller\"=>\"docs\"}, @env={...}>, @cache_control={}, @body=[\"
>   \"], @status=406, @length=0, @charset=\"utf-8\",
>   @header={\"X-UA-Compatible\"=>\"IE=Edge,chrome=1\",
>   \"X-Runtime\"=>\"0.013935\", \"Content-Type\"=>\"text/html;
>   charset=utf-8\",
>   \"Set-Cookie\"=>\"_id_session=BAh7ByIPb3JpZ2luX3VybCIYL2RvY3MuMT9mb3JtYXQ9aHRtbCIPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlNmUwZTBiZTcwM2EyYzJhY2NmMTUxMjFiMWViNTY2Njg%3D--529dbf0f8e243c4830526f37adb777bd9fba49fd;
>   path=/; HttpOnly\", \"Cache-Control\"=>\"no-cache\"}, @block=nil,
>   @writer=#,
>   @blank=true, @sending_file=false, @etag=nil,
>   @content_type=#,
>   @cookie=[]>, @_headers={\"Content-Type\"=>\"text/html\"}, @docs=[#, #, #, #, #, #], @_config=#,
>   @countries=[#, #, #],
>   @continents=[#, #], @_action_name=\"index\",
>   @_request=#\"1\",
>   \"action\"=>\"index\", \"controller\"=>\"docs\"}, @env={...}>,
>   @lookup_context=#=>{\"layouts\"=>{\"nav\"=>{true=>[app/views/layouts/_nav.html.haml]},
>   \"application\"=>{false=>[app/views/layouts/application.html.haml]},
>   \"docs\"=>{false=>[]}},
>   \"docs\"=>{\"index\"=>{false=>[app/views/docs/index.html.haml]}}}},
>   @path=\"/home/jon/id/app/views\">,
>
> @cached={#=>{\"layouts\"=>{\"docs\"=>{false=>[]}}}},
>   @path=\"/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/devise-1.4.2/app/views\">],
>   @details_key=nil, @skip_default_locale=false,
>   @details={:formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :xml, :rss,
>   :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json],
>   :handlers=>[:haml, :builder, :erb, :rjs, :rhtml, :rxml],
>   :locale=>[:en, :en]}, @frozen_formats=false>, @doc_types=[#, #], @_status=200,
>   @view_context_class=nil, @action_has_layout=true>,
>   \"rack.session.options\"=>{:secure=>false, :expire_after=>nil,
>   :domain=>nil, :httponly=>true,
>   :id=>\"6e0e0be703a2c2accf15121b1eb56668\", :path=>\"/\"},
>   \"REQUEST_METHOD\"=>\"GET\", \"warden\"=>Warden::Proxy:-616946978
>   @config={:default_scope=>:user, :failure_app=>Devise::FailureApp,
>   :intercept_401=>false, :default_strategies=>{:user=>[:rememberable,
>   :database_authenticatable]}, :scope_defaults=>{}},
>   \"rack.request.query_string\"=>\"format=html\",
>   \"rack.request.form_hash\"=>{},
>   \"action_dispatch.request.content_type\"=>#,
>   \"QUERY_STRING\"=>\"format=html\",
>   \"rack.input\"=>#}>"

and here is the response.inspect output:

> "#true}, @body=[\" \"], @status=406,
>   @length=0, @charset=\"utf-8\",
>   @header={\"X-UA-Compatible\"=>\"IE=Edge,chrome=1\",
>   \"Content-Type\"=>\"text/html; charset=utf-8\",
>   \"X-Runtime\"=>\"0.013935\",
>   \"Set-Cookie\"=>\"_id_session=BAh7ByIPb3JpZ2luX3VybCIYL2RvY3MuMT9mb3JtYXQ9aHRtbCIPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlNmUwZTBiZTcwM2EyYzJhY2NmMTUxMjFiMWViNTY2Njg%3D--529dbf0f8e243c4830526f37adb777bd9fba49fd;
>   path=/; HttpOnly\", \"Cache-Control\"=>\"no-cache\"}, @block=nil,
>   @writer=#,
>   @blank=false, @sending_file=false, @etag=nil,
>   @content_type=#,
>   @cookie=[]>"

the 'goes_to_home' test works as expected. Using the page in the development environment on my pc also works fine. Here is the server console output:

> Started GET "/docs/1" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Aug 31 05:19:20 +0200 2011 
>   Processing by DocsController#show as HTML   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
>   Doc Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `docs`.* FROM `docs` WHERE `docs`.`id` = 1
>   LIMIT 1   User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE
>   `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1   SQL (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `images`
>   WHERE (`images`.user_id = 2)   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
>   `images` WHERE (`images`.user_id = 2)   Image Load (1.9ms)  SELECT
>   `images`.* FROM `images` WHERE (`images`.user_id = 2) ORDER BY
>   updated_at DESC LIMIT 1   Print Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `prints`.* FROM
>   `prints` WHERE `prints`.`image_id` = 1 AND `prints`.`doc_id` = 1 LIMIT
>   1 Rendered layouts/_nav.html.haml (8.5ms) Rendered docs/show.html.haml
>   within layouts/application (172.7ms) Completed 200 OK in 410ms (Views:
>   225.0ms | ActiveRecord: 6.2ms)
>
> Started GET "/javascripts/dynamic_docs.js" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Aug 31
>   05:19:21 +0200 2011   Processing by JavascriptsController#dynamic_docs
>   as JS   Doc Load (16.1ms)  SELECT `docs`.* FROM `docs`   Country Load
>   (0.7ms)  SELECT `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`id`
>   = 1 LIMIT 1   CACHE (1.2ms)  SELECT `countries`.* FROM `countries`
>   WHERE `countries`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1   Country Load (0.6ms)  SELECT
>   `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
>   Country Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE
>   `countries`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1   Country Load (0.6ms)  SELECT
>   `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`id` = 18 LIMIT 1
>   Rendered javascripts/dynamic_docs.js.erb (216.0ms) Completed 200 OK in
>   270ms (Views: 238.2ms | ActiveRecord: 19.8ms)
>
> Started GET "/image_for/US-Passport/1.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Aug 31
>   05:19:21 +0200 2011 "US Passport"
>   30.0 "head_top 39" "X: 2.65000000000001, Y: 28.85, width: 222.7,
>   height: 222.7"   Processing by DocsController#image_for as HTML
>   Parameters: {"image_id"=>"1", "name"=>"US-Passport"}   User Load
>   (2.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1 
>   Image Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `images`.* FROM `images` WHERE
>   `images`.`id` = 1 AND (`images`.user_id = 2) ORDER BY updated_at DESC
>   LIMIT 1   Doc Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `docs`.* FROM `docs` WHERE
>   `docs`.`name` = 'US Passport' LIMIT 1 Rendered text template (0.1ms)
>   Sent data orange.jpg (13.2ms) Completed 200 OK in 371ms (Views: 12.9ms
>   | ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is being caused by using the wrong path in the 'get' call.

for some reason docs_url(@doc) produces "/docs.7" instead of "/docs/7"

I have opened a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262176/ralis-3-integration-test-mangles-model-pathinstance-helper) on this topic.